# Any method to get NFTs minted by a particular smart contract?

Tags: anchor, solana-program, anchor-client, nfts, fetch

My question is similar to this one [Link](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/461/mint-nfts-via-smart-contract-and-verify-they-are-minted-via-same-smart-contract).
I don't see any satisfactory answer on that question?.
Is there a method to fetch all the nfts minted by a particular smart contract?

Answer (score 1):

You can have the NFTs (mints) as a [PDA](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/26/what-is-a-program-derived-address-pda-exactly). then use [getProgramAccounts](https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#getprogramaccounts) to get the PDAs that have a data size of `82 bytes` (`mint` size)

This will return all `mint` PDAs derived from your `program`.

Comment: I did not understand having NFTs as PDA.. can u pls explain a little more..?

Comment: memcmp: {
              offset: 8,
              bytes: creator.publicKey.toBase58(),
            }                  can i add something like this to fetch nfts of specific publickey?